# Mint 19 - stuck at “Loading initial ramdisk”

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub2

I'm currently trying to set up Mint v19 on a new machine. Apart from some minor display issues (that could be avoided by going into safe mode/using nomodeset) the installation works without hickups.

The problem is that my system freezes at "Loading initial ramdisk" when booting up after restarting - i. e. when I boot from the installed OS on disk instead the live USB stick for the first time. Now this problem does not seem to be too exotic as has been discussed several times already, e. g. in Boot fails with "Loading initial ramdisk ..." and Ubuntu 16.04 fails to boot 'Loading initial ramdisk'.

I followed the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure, as noted in the second linked question, and rebooted afterwards - with the same result.

In case it's relevant: ThinkPad E485 with an AMD Ryzen 5 chip.

Any help is appreciated.

[Edit] To clarify my question: My system - as described above - does not boot, since it get's stuck after printing "Loading initial ramdisk." in the terminal. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time on this with trying different operating systems in different versions and starting them with different parameters it turned out that all it needed after installing a clean version of Mint v19 was to add `acpi=off` at the end of the corresponding line (ending with `quiet splash`) in the grub menu.

The problem is discussed in more detail here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/127989/no-acpi-support-for-my-pc-what-can-i-do.